# Can iOS and Mac OS be capable of recognising punctuations in speech-to-text transcription?

Tags: ios, mac, automator, voice-dictation

I have been using iOS for about nine years, and Mac OS X for about six, though I use dictation a lot more on my iOS device.

In any case, it is necessary to say things such as *period* or *full stop*, *comma*, *question mark*, or *exclamation point*. If you don't, your sentences will all be run-on sentences.

However, I have recently started seeing automated transcription services do a pretty decent job at detecting pauses and cadence or inflection to determine what kind of punctuation should be inserted. Here is an [example](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation) of how you can set it up using Google.

So, could this be done in practice if the means to implement it are already available?

Comment: Yes. But it’s not clear what you expect from an answer.

Comment: I would like to know if something like that is possible, and if it is, then why hasn't it been implemented at all? How would I make it known that I would like to suggest such an implementation?

Comment: You have seen that it’s possible, as you state in your question. However, I doubt that it’s possible to tell why Apple hasn’t implemented it yet. You can request that feature through Apple’s feedback page at www.apple.com/feedback, but don’t expect a reply.